# Errors and doubts in the proof.

Tags: general-topology

[image]

1:- Isn't it $\mathscr S$ insted of $\mathscr T$?

2:- I understood there is an $s\in D$ such that $s\in (a,t)(\because$ density of $D$). How does $y\in U_s$?
I know that $y\in \{x\in X:f(x)\leq a\}.$ So, $f(y)=\sup\{t\in D: y\in U_t\}\leq a <s.$

3:-How $f(y)\leq s_2$?

Comment: Note $\text{glb} = \inf$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Yes. There is obviously a typo in your text.

2: You have $f(x) = \inf \{ t \in D : x \in U_t \}$. Since $y \in \{x\in X:f(x)\leq a\}$ (i.e. $f(y) \le a$) and $a < s$, you find $t \in D \cap (a,s)$ such that $y \in U_t$. Since $t < s$, you have $U_t \subset \overline{U}_t \subset U_s$.

3: You have $y \in U_{s_2}$. Hence $f(y) = \inf \{ t \in D : y \in U_t \} \le s_2$.